# Get I/O metrics of CPU in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cpu-usage

I have been looking for metrics such as below in iOS.However with no success yet.Being new to this Unix metrics environment, I would really appreciate to get any starters or help on this.
Thanks.

`1.system.io.util - The percent of time the CPU spent waiting for IO operations to complete.`

`2.system.cpu.iowait - The percent of CPU time during which I/O requests were issued to the device`

In the details of `task_wait_state_info` there is a struct available as below:

```
struct task_wait_state_info {
uint64_t  total_wait_state_time;    /* Time that all threads past and present have been in a wait state */
uint64_t  total_wait_sfi_state_time;    /* Time that threads have been in SFI wait (should be a subset of total wait state time */
uint32_t  _reserved[4];
};


task_wait_state_info_data_t waittime;
NSLog(@"Wait time : %llu",waittime.total_wait_state_time);
```

Is this the same wait time as in the `1.system.io.util` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a software project called GodEye on github which has working swift code which answers your questions.  Take a look at: https://github.com/zixun/GodEye

```
•   monitor for the log and point out log type.
•   monitor for the crash, include Uncatched Exception and Signal.
•   monitor for the network, all information of request and response.
•   monitor for the ANR, tell you the stacktrace of all threads.
•   monitor for the memory leak, tell you the leak object's class name.
•   a terminal for you to customized your commands and things what to do.
•   monitor for the cpu usage of system and application.
•   monitor for the ram usage of system and application.
•   monitor for the FPS.
•   monitor for the netflow of system and application.
•   a file browser for look through the sandbox, .app and root directory.
•   custom and runtime setting
```